# Cannot initialize type "x" with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to join 3 tables using linq to sql and a ViewModel, pass the query to the View and display the results, but it doesn't work.

**Update**
DbContext Class:

```
public partial class DbEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bar> Bars{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Fubar> Fubars{ get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Foo Foo{ get; set; }
    public Bar Bar{ get; set; }
    public Fubar Fubar{ get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
    {
      //var db = new MyViewModel();  //wrong
        var db = new DbEntities();

        var query = (from f in db.Foos
                     join b in db.Bars on f.IDFoo equals b.IDFoo
                     join fb in db.Fubars on b.IDBar equals fb.IDBar
                     select new MyViewModel { 
                                f.IDFoo,
                                f.NameFoo, 
                                f.CityFoo, 
                                b.NameBar, 
                                fb.NameFubar });


        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.NameFubar.Contains(searchString));
        }
        return View(query);
    }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Proj.Models.MyViewModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <p>
            @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
            <input type="submit" class="no-button" value="Search" />
        </p>
    }

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <div class="title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NameFubar)</div><br />
   ...

}
```

I get the following error:

```
1. "Cannot initialize type 'Proj.Models.MyViewModel' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I had to set proprieties not classes in MyViewModel:

```
public short IDFoo { get; set; }
public string NameFoo { get; set; }
public string CityFoo { get; set; }
public string NameBar { get; set; }
public string NameFubar { get; set; }
```

And in the linq query I was using the collection initializer not the object initializer:

```
select new MyViewModel {
       IDFoo = f.IDFoo,
       NameFoo = f.NameFoo,
       CityFoo = f.CityFoo,
       NameBar = b.NameBar,
       NameFubar = fb.NameFubar 
       };
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make much sense. You are creating a new instance of your view model, `MyViewModel` where navigation properties **are not** enumerables (!) and try to join on these?

Shouldn't you rather start with an instance of your db context? I do believe you should.

```
    var db = new SomethingThatIsADbContext();

    var query = (from f in db.Foos
                 join b in db.Bars on f.IDFoo equals b.IDFoo
                 join fb in db.Fubars on b.IDBar equals fb.IDBar
                 select new MyViewModel { 
                            f.IDFoo,
                            f.NameFoo, 
                            f.CityFoo, 
                            b.NameBar, 
                            fb.NameFubar }).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks! ok, now I am getting this error: "Cannot initialize type 'Proj.Models.MyViewModel' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' ".

Comment: You are calling a constructor on the `MyViewModel` without parameters but then you are initializing it with an anonymous object of 5 members. I think this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

if you write this

```
query = query.Where(x => x.NameFubar.Contains(searchString));
```

performance very bad, you can where in your linq code.